# PHP Domdocument use saveXML instead of save

Tags: php

I am creating an XML file in PHP like this...

```
$myXML = new DOMDocument();
$myXML ->formatOutput = true;

$data = $myXML ->createElement('data');
$data->nodeValue = 'mydata';
$final->appendChild($data);

$myXML ->save('/mypath/myfile.xml');
```

This works, but how can I convert this to use saveXML() instead? I have tried like this but I get nothing

```
$myXML->saveXML();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: saveXML() returns a string you need to echo it or assign a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things:

- `$final` is not declared. Change it.
- In case saveXML() is called, the output has to be assigned to a variable or printed

Here goes the working code:

```
<?php
$myXML = new DOMDocument();
$myXML ->formatOutput = true;

$data = $myXML ->createElement('data');
$data->nodeValue = 'mydata';
$myXML->appendChild($data);

echo $myXML ->saveXML();
?>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>mydata</data>
```